# Report how long between two specific states of an Azure Devops work item - Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I am trying to perform a simple task for Azure Devops work item type Release.  All we need to know is how many days between State - Testing to State - Documentation for these items.  If this was historical data in some SQL table, it's no question for me what to do but it seems there isn't any simple way to report on this within Azure Devops. I would like to be able to do this all within Devops itself without having to use excel, some external app.  just simply be able to see it right in devops.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is accomplished by adding an extra field to store the state transition time and adding a rule that populates that field when the work item is put into that state. Then you can simply query these two dates and diff them.